# joins query for associated model in DESC order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

Question model has_many Answer. How to count amount of answers question has and order accordingly in DESC order? I use joins method.

How could I make the most answered questions DESC order?

**UPDATED**

Here is how to make the most answered question DESC order:

```
@questions = Question.find(:all,
                           joins: :answers,
                          select: ' "questions".*, count("answers".id) as answers_count', 
                          group: '"questions".id',
                          order: "answers_count DESC")
```

VIEW

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<%= question.answers_count %>
<%= end %>
```

I have another issue now. I use ransack gem. How do I add .ransack(params[:q]) to @questions array?

Answer (score 0):

if `params[:q]` is what tells you how many answers a question has, I think you could do

```
Question.tagged_with(params[:tag]).joins(answers: :user).uniq.ransack(params[:q]).order("params[:q] DESC")
```

But that's not tested, so not sure.  check out the documentation on ordering [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) and you should be able to get it!

You can also put the results of that query in your original post, that will help to figure it out if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for respond! Maybe you could look at updated question and suggest something? I found how to make answered questions in DESC order, however can't grasp how to add .ransack(params[:q]) to the @questions array.

Comment: don't know much about ransack, sorry!